# error using rails_script gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

## Problem:

I am attempting to learn the rails_script gem by following the tutorial on the gem's [github page](https://github.com/gemgento/rails_script). I added the gem to my Gemfile, bundled it, and ran this commands:

```
rails g rails_script:install
```

Then I added the line:

```
<%= include_rails_script %>
```

to:

### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RailsScript</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data- turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= include_rails_script %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I generated a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold posts title:string content:text
```

After generating the scaffold, I had three coffee script files in my app/assets/javascripts directory:

```
javascripts
    |
    |
    +---> base.coffee
    |
    +---> global.coffee
    |
    +---> posts.coffee
```

My posts.coffee file looks like this:

```
window.App ||= {}
class App.Posts extends App.Base

  beforeAction: (action) =>
    return

  afterAction: (action) =>
    return

  index: =>
    alert "index page!"
    return

  show: =>
    alert "show page!"
    return

  new: =>
    alert "new page!"
    return

  edit: =>
    alert "edit page!"
    return
```

When I run the rails server and access any of the controller/actions listed in posts.coffee, I get the following errors:

[image: console errors]

Does anyone know what is going on..I am quite confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you ran `rails g rails_script:install`? The error message you're getting is consistent with forgetting that command.

Comment: Yes I double checked but I had already run that command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `//= require rails_script` before the `//= require_tree .` in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js in assets folder.